# Strange Issue CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) in 3G

Tags: ios, web-services, ssl, soap, sslhandshakeexception

I have a strange issue with my iOS application.
I need to call a ws (SOAP). I can not act on the server. The service I use is not in my possession. I can only call this service.

From several days I have always a strange problem.

This is the scenario:

I use an *iPhone* with *iOS 7.1*

I use a **3G data connection** using the **Vodafone IT** as the operator.

When I first launch the application and I call the service that works fine.

When I reuse the application after some time..some minutes (for example, by opening it from background mode) I have the problem.

The WS is not called correctly.... I think it's an SSL issue.

This is a log that is printed (automatically) when the request fails:

> CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)

I use a simple `NSURLConnection`.

Here is a summary of the situation:

- Using a WiFi connection: OK, it works great
- Using a 3G connection with Vodafone: NO, SSLHandshake failed
- Using a 3G connection with a *different manager of Vodafone*: OK, it works great.

I can not explain this strange situation. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue in iOS 8.1.1.

Comment: Any solution for this problem?